# Creating an MS Word document in an Android App

Tags: android, xml, ms-word, .doc

I am working on a client project for an android app and wanted to confirm if the designed solution appears to be utilizing the most appropriate technology and resources.

The application gathers data from the user via a series of questions, compiles the data into a single human-readable document, then sends the document out via email. My client requires the delivered doc to be in MS Word format. I am currently building my doc in the app using xml, setting the extension type as ".doc", then sending. Since the latest versions of MS Word seem to have no problem handling these types of files, this seems to be the most appropriate solution.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing? Should I be handling this another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't writing DOC files correctly. If really need to save .DOC files I suggest you read [this .pdf regarding thd DOC file format](http://sc.openoffice.org/compdocfileformat.pdf) put out by the OpenOffice team.

As you are already writing the file in XML consider using [Microsoft's Office XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) instead of writing the XML to a .DOC file.

Comment: great! If you feel like my answer helped would you consider voting up and or accepting this answer?